# What would cause a data grid error on an image column only when deployed on a Windows 10 machine?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, datagrid, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewimagecolumn

I have a C# windows forms app with a data grid.  One column of the grid is an image column which I put a bitmap in.  It works fine on the Windows 10 machine I developed it on and when I deploy it on Windows 7 machines, but on all other Windows 10 machines I get an error.  The error is "System.FormatException: Formatted value of the cell has a wrong type."  I haven't been able to recreate the error on my development machine, so I'm not sure how to figure out what's wrong.  I thought it might be occurring because some prerequisite was not included when I deploy it (it's a Click Once application), but I don't see anything missing.  I thought maybe it couldn't find the links to the image, so I tried drawing them instead and still got the same error.  I'm guessing it has to do with my bitmap column, but I don't know why it would work on my machine and Windows 7 machines and not other Windows 10 machines.  Any ideas on what's happening and/or how to fix this?

Here is the designer for my grid:
[image]

Here is the DefaultCellStyle settings.  I thought the NullValue might be the cause.  I originally had System.Drawing.Bitmap in it.  I tried using null, but still get an error.
[image]

Here's the code for how I populate that column.

```
 Bitmap bmpCombineOnly = new Bitmap(1, 1);

 Bitmap bmpYellow = new Bitmap(26, 26);
 Graphics grYellow = Graphics.FromImage(bmpYellow);
 grYellow.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Yellow, 2), 0, 0, 25, 25);
 grYellow.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow), 0, 0, 25, 25);

 bmpCombineOnly = bmpYellow;

 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ItemsInLocationDataGridView.Rows)
 {
     row.Cells["Icon"].Value = bmpCombineOnly;
 }
```

Comment: That NullValue field in the propertygrid is appropriate for text columns but not an image column.  Yes it displays the string "System.Drawing.Bitmap", but that is the result of `BitmapInstance.Tostring()`.  If you enter some text in the property grid, it will store that string value which is inappropriate for a cell expecting a bitmap value.  Find the line in the form's designer file that assigns a string to `Nullvalue and delete it to restore the default.

Comment: So, you have a Column named `Icon`. Does it even compile with that name? + You're leaking Graphics resources: none of the object you created is being disposed of. I don't get the use of this: `bmpCombineOnly = bmpYellow;`.